# Virtual host Tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 7.I have my domain which pointed to `qlhd.viweb.vn`.Now I have some problem when I try to access my domain through internet. It always redirect to tomcat host manager page not my page. If I want to access my page I have to go through this http://qlhd.viweb.vn/CMS link.
I researched Google and add it to my server.xml

```
<Host name="www.qlhd.viweb.vn" appBase="webapps"
unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</Host>
```